# Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting above warning every time for following code.

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {               
        var $lmTable = $("#information").dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sScrollX": "1000px",
            "sScrollY": calcDataTableHeight(),
            "sSearch": "Search all:",
            "aaData": [],
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "senderCompID", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "targetCompID", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "tradSesReqID", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "sendingTime", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "tradingSessionID", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "messageType", sDefaultContent: "n/a"}
            ]
        });
```

**html**

```
   <table id="information" class="display">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SENDER COMP ID</th>
                <th>TARGET COMP ID</th>
                <th>TRADE SESSION REQ ID</th>
                <th>SENDING TIME</th>
                <th>TRADING SESSION ID</th>
                <th>MESSAGE TYPE</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="infoBody">
            </tbody>
   </table>
```

**JSON response**

```
[
 {
    "senderCompID":"1159",
    "targetCompID":"CASE",
    "tradSesReqID":"1308042969531",
    "sendingTime":"Jun 14, 2011 9:00:56 AM",
    "tradingSessionID":"SME",
    "messageType":"g"
  }
]
```

I am getting following error when loading the page and table row is not loading.

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'information'): Requested unknown
parameter '0' from the data source for row 0
```

What is the issue here and what will be the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**Diagnosis**:

Look at your initialisation of Datatables.. you are setting aaData (i.e. the data source) to an empty array on initialisation. In other words, as soon as datatables makes your table, it tries to read the first column from your empty array and returns that warning

**Solution**:

Get your JSON response before you initialise the table.

```
...    

//Get your json from the server

var aaData = [
{
    "senderCompID":"1159",
    "targetCompID":"CASE",
    "tradSesReqID":"1308042969531",
    "sendingTime":"Jun 14, 2011 9:00:56 AM",
    "tradingSessionID":"SME",
    "messageType":"g"
  }
]

//Then initialise the table
```

OR ... Assuming you are using Ajax

```
var aaData = null;

$.ajax("*put your url here*")
.done(function(response){
    aaData = response;

    // Then initialise table 
});
```

Here is the entire code using Ajax to get the data;

```
$(document).ready(function () {    

    $.ajax("*put your url here*")
    .done(function(response){

        //Set the variable aaData to the response
        var aaData = response;

        // Then initialise table using aaData as the datasource

        var $lmTable = $("#information").dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sScrollX": "1000px",
            "sScrollY": calcDataTableHeight(),
            "sSearch": "Search all:",
            "aaData": aaData,    // <-- Here
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "senderCompID", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "targetCompID", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "tradSesReqID", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "sendingTime", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "tradingSessionID", sDefaultContent: "n/a"},
                { "mDataProp": "messageType", sDefaultContent: "n/a"}
            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: how to set `var aaData = [data from server] ` here?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? Using $.ajax?